# xCode build downloaded library

Tags: ios, xcode, restkit

I have been trying to add the Restkit framework to my project. I have downloaded the source and followed the [instructions](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-v0.20.x-as-a-Git-Submodule) to link to my project. However I find the files I downloaded to be highlighted in "Red" in xcode. When I checked the path where xcode expects the file to be, it was empty.

Here's how the files of Restkit are being shown in XCode right now.

[image: Screenshot from Xcode]

I guess I need to "build" the Restkit project first so that the libraries are present and then link them. How should I go about it?

Comment: The products are only created when the project is built...

Answer (score 0):

Usually the red files mean they are not existent in the current file directory as the other files. Re-add the frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your life a million times easier by using [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org).

It's a framework dependency manager.

Use the website to search for the framework (RestKit in this case) and follow the instruction to add it to your project.

Cocoapods will the download and install the RestKit framework for you without having to worry about linking or copying etc...